# Why is my CSS for navigation items not working?

Tags: html, css

Alright, so I have no idea why this isn't working, but take a look. My top right navigation items are terribly screwed up. Everything else works great so far. Any suggestions would be much appreciated. Also, side-note, is there a way for me to have an "a" tag that heads to a directory (Music) and for me to customize the directory page? I'll make a separate question on that in a minute. Also, I would love to have my own player that shows metadata. Anyway, I'll try to stay on topic so you don't have to answer those, just the CSS help. Thanks!

**The HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head lang="en">
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="description" content="AnonSeeker is a collection of HTML, CSS, and JavaScript files designed for privacy. We offer things such as a browser, bookmarks, proxies, music, a text/code editor, and much more, completely password-protected!">
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
        <!-- CSS Stylesheet -->
        <link type="image/x-icon" rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico">
        <!-- Favicon -->
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- All Navigation Items -->
        <div class="container" id="all-navigation">
            <!-- Top Left Navigation Items -->
            <div class="container" id="top-left-naviagtion">
                <!-- Goto Browser -->
                <div class="container goto-browser top-left-navigation-item">
                    <a href="html/anon-seeker-browser.html" class="goto-browser top-left-navigation-item">
                        <img src="img/browser.png" alt="browser-img" class="goto-browser top-left-navigation-item">
                    </a>
                </div>
                <!-- Goto Bookmarks -->
                <div class="container goto-bookmarks top-left-navigation-item">
                    <a href="html/bookmarks.html" class="goto-bookmarks top-left-navigation-item">
                        <img src="img/bookmarks.png" alt="bookmarks-img" class="goto-bookmarks top-left-navigation-item">
                    </a>
                </div>
                <!-- Goto Music -->
                <div class="container goto-music top-left-navigation-item">
                    <a href="html/music.html" class="goto-music top-left-navigation-item">
                        <img src="img/music.png" alt="music-img" class="goto-music top-left-navigation-item">
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- Top Right Naviagtion Items -->
            <div class="conatiner" id="top-right-navigation">
                <div class="container goto-ace top-right-navigation-item">
                    <a href="html/ace-editor.html" class="goto-ace top-right-navigation-item">
                        <img src="img/ace-editor.png" alt="ace-editor-img" class="goto-ace top-right-navigation-item">
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Middle Elements -->
        <div class="container" id="middle-elements">
            <!-- Center AnonSeeker Image -->
            <div class="container middle-img">
                <img src="img/anonseeker.png" alt="anonseeker.png" class="middle-img">
            </div>
            <div class="container search-box">
                <input type="text" placeholder="Search" class="search-box">
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**The CSS**

```
html, body {
    margin: 0;
}

#all-navigation {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

#top-right-navigation {
    top: 10px;
    right: 10px;
    padding: 15px;
}

#top-left-navigation {
    top: 10px;
    left: 10px;
    padding: 15px;
}

.top-right-navigation-item {
    padding: 5px;
}

.top-left-navigation-item {
    padding: 5px;
}

#middle-elements {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 5px;
}
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`top-left-navigation` spelling wrong in your html so not working your css. Just replace CSS mentioned below code. Hope this will help you

```
#top-right-navigation {
    position:absolute;
    top: 10px;
    right: 10px;
    padding: 15px;
}
#top-left-naviagtion{
    position:absolute;
    top: 10px;
    left: 10px;
    padding: 15px;
}
```